# Implement custom Autoplay on Chromecast Receiver

Tags: chromecast, autoplay, receiver

Question #1:
How do we make sure the built-in UI showing the next media information is never shown? (We want to display our own UI)

Question #2:
What is the best method to make the receiver play the next item when we decide to?

We are implementing our receiver on top of the CAF Receiver (V3). We are looking to implement the autoplay logic in Javascript on the receiver, not the sender.

Thanks!